# $L^2$ estimate of heat equation solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose $u$ is a solution of the heat equation below:

$$u_t-\Delta u=0 \ in\  U\times (0,T) $$
$$u=0 \ on \ \partial U\times (0,T) $$
$$u=g \ on \ U\times \{t=0\} $$

Where $U$ is a bounded open set in $R^n$ and $g\in L^2(U)$,
Can we have this estimate :

$$\int_U u(x,T)^2 dx\leq \lambda\int_U g^2 dx$$

Where $0<\lambda <1$ is a constant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simple case $g \equiv 0$ we get $0 \leq 0$ and we are happy. Otherwise, multiply the equation by $u$, identify the left side as $\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} u^2$. Then integrate both sides and interchange. Defining $E(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int_U u^2 dx$, we have

$$\frac{dE}{dt} = \int_U u \Delta u dx.$$

Now integrate by parts:

$$\frac{dE}{dt} = \int_{\partial U} u (\nabla u \cdot n) dS - \int_U |\nabla u|^2 dx \\
= -\int_U |\nabla u|^2 dx$$

using the boundary condition. Motivated by the exponential decay that we see when we use separation of variables on simple domains, we'd like to say that this is less than $-cE$ for some $c>0$.

Provided the boundary is nice enough (Lipschitz turns out to be sufficient), this follows from the Sobolev inequality (although this might be overkill; I've been dealing with this topic this week, so it's on my mind). Applying it in the case $p=2$, we get that

$$\| u \|_{L^{p^*}} \leq C \| \nabla u \|_{L^2}$$

where $p^* = \frac{2n}{n-2}$. Since the domain is bounded and $p^* > 2$, $\| u \|_{L^2} \leq C' \| u \|_{L^{p^*}}$, so $\| u \|_{L^2} \leq C'' \| \nabla u \|_{L^2}$ where $C''=C C'$.

A warning: here I am using the variant of the Sobolev inequality involving $W_0^{1,2}(U)$, not all of $W^{1,2}(U)$. Over all of $W^{1,2}(U)$, we get $C \| u \|_{W^{1,2}}$ on the right side, which would break this argument. But $u \in W_0^{1,2}(U)$ in this context because of the boundary condition.

So returning to our original problem, the minus sign flips the inequalities, so we have

$$-\int_U |\nabla u|^2 dx \leq -cE.$$

This can be rewritten as

$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{ct} E \leq 0$$

from which it follows that

$$e^{c T} E(T) \leq E(0)$$

which gives the result.

Note that this proof does *not* work if $n=1$ or $n=2$. If $n=1$ you can just write down the explicit solution with separation of variables, and the form of the solution gives the answer immediately. I'm not sure how to handle the case $n=2$. Edit: as Famous Blue Raincoat pointed out in the comments, there is actually no problem when $n=1$ or $n=2$; the above goes through regardless.

Also note that there is a smoothing argument to be made if $g$ does not have a weak derivative in $L^2$. But this is routine: you have the desired inequality if you replace $g$ by $u(t,x)$ for any $t>0$ (since $u$ is in fact $C^\infty$ for $t>0$), and you just need that $\lim_{t \to 0^+} u = g$ in the sense of $L^2$.

Comment: @Ylath I added in two paragraphs that add important caveats.

Comment: You always have $\| u \|_{L^2} \leq C'' \| \nabla u \|_{L^2}$ for $W^{1,2}_0$ functions, in every dimension. This is a variant of the Poincaré inequality, but also follows from Sobolev inequality, since $2<2^*$ in all dimensions.

Comment: Instead of Gronwall's lemma, rewrite $E'\le -cE$ as $(e^{ct}E)'\le 0$ and conclude.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat The latter is actually somewhat of a problem, because I think that $(e^{ct} E)' \leq 0$ only implies that $E \leq C e^{-ct}$ for some $C$ which might actually be larger than $E(0)$. The former is very helpful, however!

Comment: Since the function $e^{ct}E$ is nonincreasing, its value at $T$ does not exceed its value at $0$. That is, $e^{cT}E(T)\le E(0)$.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat I see what you mean. Nice again!